# Privacy Policy in UWP Store App ? Submission App Store Certification failed

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps

I have a simple application to calculate  the IP address, subnet mask, broadcast, range of IP addresses, the number of available IP addresses and CIDR.

> App Policies: 10.5.1 
>   Privacy Policy
>   Notes To Developer
>   Because your app accesses personal information, you need to supply a working link to a privacy policy in the “privacy url” field when you submit the app. See policy 10.5.1 for details about the requirements for a privacy policy.

But my app does not collect any user data, its work like simple calculator for Desktop or Mobile Devices.

1. Is it always necessary to have completed a URL link to your website
   PP, where you store your Privacy Policy, or you can use something
   universal like universal URL with Privacy Policy informations?
2. Maybe I fill or check something wrong the Submission form on Store Dev Acc after I requested this item to validation?
3. If the URL Privacy Policy required in Store Submission, it is necessary to put into application page Privacy Policy text Also, as was the case with WP 8.x applications.?

My application is FREE

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the capabilities of the application may mean it gets categorised as accessing personal information. For example might think it gets the user's IP address which would be classed as personal information - you can always set up a github pages account then put your privacy policy there stating what happens with the IP address ie. nothing if that's the case and hopefully will help pass certification

Comment: Thanks, but application works only with input data, app does not add any data from user device like actual IP or something like that

Comment: But in capabilities i have a check Internet (Client), i try it without it

Comment: Hopefully that will work, it could be the IP address thing got detected and it assumed it uses them rather than calculates them by having no internet capability if it's not needed might make submission easier, worth a try!

Comment: Yes, AFAIK, Internet (Client) capability requires you to provide the Privacy Policy link. So removing this capability, if you do not really need it, should help.

Comment: I remove it, but i got still same message and certification take little bit longer in this time.

Comment: I think the name and description of your app is probably flagging something, just at a glace I'd assume your app uses IP addresses, I'd just write a privacy policy that states that any IPs are not actually broadcasted or used from your app and host that on GitHub pages as that's free - I can't guarantee anything but hopefully that might help?