# How do I deal with the APPX0501 error stating that "the element specified requires "runFullTrust" capability"?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, desktop-bridge

Whilst trying to create a package (appx upload) to upload to the Windows Store, I am being told by Visual Studio 2017 that a "runFullTrust" capability is mandatory.

I have tried removing the "runFullTrust" tag along with the Capabilities tag, as my app requires no capabilities and the project won't build because it says "runFullTrust" is mandatory. So in order for the project to build, I added the necessary capability in my Package.appxmanifest file but then when I upload my successfully built package to the store, the store requires a privacy policy from me. I don't have a privacy policy and my app does not require absolutely anything from users. It's a Winforms app converted to UWP and it's a Tic Tac Toe game. Nothing is requested from my users. It's simply a grid onto which the user clicks. It has a couple text boxes, holds the player turns and keeps the score. The app does not access anything personal to the user or requests anything from the user.

I have referred to Microsoft Docs which are horrendous guides and I have looked up what "runFulltrust" is and why it's needed. I have also checked third party sites but no solution seems to be available. Microsoft Docs has a submission guide and app requirements but nothing like this seems to be covered. I have also checked this link [Privacy Policy in UWP Store App ? Submission App Store Certification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668754/privacy-policy-in-uwp-store-app-submission-app-store-certification-failed) but it doesn't seem to cover my problem. Below is the tag I now have in my Package.appxmanifest with which the solution builds successfully.

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="runFullTrust"/>
</Capabilities>
```

The build succeeds but the store requires a privacy policy from me. No privacy policy should be needed as I explicitly state that one isn't needed because I don't request anything from users but when the package uploads windows store changes this option to a Yes which means I need a privacy policy to submit. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just visit http://www.myapppolicy.com/ and fill up the form, copy the URL of the privacy policy, and paste it back in the app submission form. Done.

Answer (score 2):

Converted Win32/Winforms/WPF apps run with the full privileges of the user (aka run at full trust), hence the capability 'runFullTrust' needs to be declared and disclosed to the end user.

Unlike UWP apps that run in the appcontainer, classic desktop apps (such as Winforms apps) can access all files, registry, location etc. without enforced user consent, therefore the store requires a privacy policy.

To solve it you have two options:
a) provide the required privacy policy for your app - or
b) rewrite the app as UWP

Comment: Thanks. How does one start writing a privacy for something like that?

Comment: I won't be able to provide legal advise, and of course it will depend on your app. You can search the web for examples and templates for app policies, and you can look at app policies for existing apps in the Microsoft Store as well as other app stores.